# seasonal adjustment to testset

Tags: python, time-series, prediction, seasonality

I would like to understand how to apply a seasonal adjustment to my testset. Let's imagine we have a time series and divide it into trainigset (80% of the samples) and testset (20% of the samples). I proceed with the seasonal decomposition of the training set, using STL, and at this point I can remove the trend component and the seasonality component from my trainigset. But if I want to do the same on my testset, how can I do this? I would not go and apply the decomposition directly on the test set, but I should be able to use the components from the trainigset decomposition. How can I proceed?
Are there different paths I can take that would lead me to the same result?

A different approach I have found could be to calculate the trend using a linear model on the trainingset and then do a forcast on the test set, and for seasonality reconstruct periodic signals with the Fourier transform and "extend" them for the length of the test set. But I don't know if this is right.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import MSTL

np.random.seed(0)
date = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', end='1/01/2023')
monthly_seasonality = np.sin(date.month/12*2*np.pi)
annual_seasonality = np.sin(date.year/2023*2*np.pi)
noise = np.random.normal(0, 0.5, len(date))
trend = 0.002 * np.arange(len(date))
value =trend + monthly_seasonality + annual_seasonality + noise 

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': date, 'target': value})

#time feature extraction
def timeFeatureExtraction(df):
    df['year'] = df['date'].dt.year
    df['month'] = df['date'].dt.month
    return df
timeFeatureExtraction(df)

#train test split
train, test = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.2, shuffle=False)

X_train = train.drop(columns=['target', 'date'])
y_train = train['target']
X_test = test.drop(columns=['target', 'date'])
y_test = test['target']

#%% PLOT TRAINIG DATA 
# Plotting the training set
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.plot(train['date'], y_train, label='y_train')
plt.title('Time Series: y_train')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Target')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

#%% MULTIPLE SEASONALITY DECOMPOSITION
mstl = MSTL(y_train, periods=[28, 365])
res = mstl.fit()
ax = res.plot()
#%% CLEAN DATA FROM TREND AND SEASONALITY
seasonal_28 = res.seasonal["seasonal_28"]
seasonal_365 = res.seasonal["seasonal_365"]
trend = res.trend
```